# Why Aren't My Chef Normal Attributes Persisted?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I need to persist some values between runs of chef-client on a node. From the [Chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) I thought normal attributes where intended for this

> "At the beginning of a chef-client run, all default, override, and
>   automatic attributes are reset...Normal attributes are never
>   reset...At the conclusion of the chef-client run, all default,
>   override, and automatic attributes disappear, leaving only a
>   collection of normal attributes that will persist until the next
>   chef-client run.")

However, if I bootstrap a node with following recipe **twice**

```
log 'message' do
  message "Before setting I am #{node['my_key']}"
  level :warn
end

node.normal['my_key'] = 'my value'

log 'message' do
  message "After setting I am #{node['my_key']}"
  level :warn
end
```

I would expect the to see

> Before setting I am my value

on the 2nd run (as the value was persisted from the 1st run). However it reverts to unset again.

Is it possible for the value to persist? Do I need to run the recipe in a different way? Or is it just not possible?

**EDIT**: As far as I can see the Chef run completes successfully. Here is the command and output:

```
mfreake@my-linux:/export/apps/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks$ knife bootstrap node1.blah.com --ssh-user mfreake --ssh-password 'yaddayadda' --sudo --use-sudo-password  --bootstrap-proxy 'http://proxy.blah.com/' -N node1 --run-list persist_test::read_set_read
Node node1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y
Client node1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y
Creating new client for node1
Creating new node for node1
Connecting to node1.marketpipe.com
node1.blah.com [sudo] password for mfreake: -----> Existing Chef installation detected
node1.blah.com Starting first Chef Client run...
node1.blah.com Starting Chef Client, version 12.4.2
node1.blah.com resolving cookbooks for run list: ["persist_test::read_set_read"]
node1.blah.com Synchronizing Cookbooks:
node1.blah.com   - persist_test
node1.blah.com Compiling Cookbooks...
node1.blah.com [2015-09-30T17:45:40+01:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for log[message] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
node1.blah.com [2015-09-30T17:45:40+01:00] WARN: Previous log[message]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/persist_test/recipes/read_set_read.rb:2:in `from_file'
node1.blah.com [2015-09-30T17:45:40+01:00] WARN: Current  log[message]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/persist_test/recipes/read_set_read.rb:9:in `from_file'
node1.blah.com Converging 2 resources
node1.blah.com Recipe: persist_test::read_set_read
node1.blah.com   * log[message] action write[2015-09-30T17:45:40+01:00] WARN: A message add to the log. 
node1.blah.com 
node1.blah.com   
node1.blah.com   * log[message] action write[2015-09-30T17:45:40+01:00] WARN: A message add to the log. my value
node1.blah.com 
node1.blah.com   
node1.blah.com 
node1.blah.com Running handlers:
node1.blah.com Running handlers complete
node1.blah.com Chef Client finished, 2/2 resources updated in 1.621458795 seconds
```

Comment: 1) Does your chef run end successfully ? if not nothing is saved back to the server. 2) If you launch chef-client with `-o recipe` the node object is not saved either. Are you really out of this two cases ? (For your last question, yes it's possible and intended)

Comment: Thanks it seems to complete successfully. I've added the command and output above. Is the output "Node node1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N)" - the problem? How do I not overwrite it?

Comment: Indeed bootstrap should be used only once, to bootstrap (create the node object, create the client key, install chef-client and do first run). As you're redoing it, it overwrite the node object, so obviously it's empty on the run. Trigger the run via knife ssh for example and all will be ok.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, that explains a lot. The idea of bootstrap-ing a node multiple times didn't sound right. I'm using the Learning Chef book and maybe I've just missed that bit (although I still can't see it or find it in the index.). Thanks - feel free to put that as an answer if you want points/ticks

Comment: If the book target chef11 it's normal, the behavior has lightly changed in chef12 where the validator key is not copied to node for it to register itself but create the node in advance. I'll try to summarize that in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there's two cases where a node state, including attributes could be not saved back on the chef-server:

1. When the run end in error (here depending on the error, the state could be saved anyway, but it's out of scope for this question)
2. Running `chef-client -o any_recipe_list` the `-o`option is here to temporarily override the runlist, so it won't save back to the chef-server to not overwrite the actual run list.

`node.normal` and `node.set` are the same thing, writing values in the node object to be stored on the server. [Examples in the documentation on the attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#examples)

Here the problem is due to the use of `knife bootstrap` (with version > 12.1 as per the [documentation on the validator less bootstrap](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#examples)) which start by creating the node on the chef-server and its client key. Calling it twice and allowing it to overwrite previous object reset the whole node object.

The `bootstrap` shoudl be used only once, any chef-client run later should be triggered by another way (crontab, knife ssh, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You should try `node.set['my_key'] = 'my value'` (or use `node.set_unless`, to make it safe to keep if someone changes the attribute on your chef server).

Comment: `set` being an alias for `normal`, this won't solve the OP problem.

Comment: @Tensbai do you have a link to that? I actually searched the codebase last night and couldn't find the `def` for it. Hence my post saying "you should try..." instead of "I know the answer is X" :)

Comment: See the link to attribute docs above, from the codebase it's the alias line [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node.rb#L204) wich alias the normal method just above. `node['key'] =  value` could be used too in the same goal and is delegated to the `Chef::Node::Attribute` class defined [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node/attribute.rb). I personnaly stick to use the `node['key']` form to read attributes and `node.method['key']` to set them (where method could be any of the attribute precedence)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I searched for `def set` but didn't think to look for aliases! :)